# Evaluate $\int_{\beta}xe^y|dz|$, where $\beta(s)=(1+s^2)^{-1}(1-s^2+2is)$ for $s$ in the interval $[-1,1]$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

**Evaluate $\int_{\beta}xe^y|dz|$, where $\beta(s)=(1+s^2)^{-1}(1-s^2+2is)$ for $s$ in the interval $[-1,1]$**

I have applied the definition and got to the next integral $\int_{-1}^{1}((1-s^2)/(1+s^2))e^{2s/(1+s^2)}(\sqrt{(\frac{-4s}{(1+s^2)^2})^2+ (\frac{2-4s^2}{(1+s^2)^2})^2}ds$, is there any other simpler way to do this or how can this integral be solved? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $|dz|$ is wrong. Recalculate it and let $s=\tan\theta$ then you will find the solution. In the other hand $\beta=\dfrac{1-s^2+2is}{1+s^2}=\dfrac{1+is}{1-is}$ with $s\in[-1,1]$, so $\beta(s)$ maps $[-1,1]$ to right semicircle of $|z|=1$. With $z=e^{it}$ where $t\in[-\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{\pi}{2}]$ we have
$$\int_\beta xe^y|dz|=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos te^{\sin t}dt=e^{\sin t}\Big|_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}=e-\dfrac1e$$

Comment: Why $β(s)$  maps $[−1,1]$ to right semicircle of $|z|=1$? Why $x=\cos t$ and $y=\sin t$?

Comment: $|\beta(s)|=1$ with starting $\beta(-1)=-i$ ending at $\beta(1)=i$. $x={\bf Re}\,e^{it}=\cos t$.